# Cron job fails to run python script

Tags: cron

I can't get cron to run my Python script.  Below is my crontab entry:

```
0 22 * * * /usr/bin/python3.5 /home/gmoreno/hue.py > /tmp/log
```

Syslog shows the crontab run at set time but my Hue lights don't turn on.  When I run the script manually the lights turn on.

Comment: I've tried /usr/bin/python instead of the /usr/bin/python3.5 and had the same result

Comment: Please post your error log and [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/883886/edit) your question.

Comment: That's the thing I don't get an error in syslog and /tmp/log is empty.

Comment: edit your crontab with `0 22 * * * /usr/bin/python3.5 /home/gmoreno/hue.py >> /tmp/log 2>&1`

Comment: Thanks Lnux I was able to figure out what the problem was with that.  I had been scratching my head for hours on this.

Comment: What was the issue? I think you didn't ask question properly.  I assumed that question is regarding log.

Comment: It was related to how the Python hue library was working.  I had to connect to the Hue bridge and press the button.  It wouldn't have been a problem if I would have done a cron job with the user that had already connected to the Hue bridge.  I didn't realize this was the issue until I got the logging working properly, thanks to your help.

Answer (score -1):

set path in crontab,

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
0 22 * * * /usr/bin/python3.5 /home/gmoreno/hue.py
```